# Where does Buddha mention about Sanatana dharma (Hinduism)?

Tags: hinduism, scripture

Hindupedia states, on its page about the [Sanātan Dharma principle](http://hindupedia.com/en/San%C4%81tan_Dharma_principle#Buddhism), that:

> Although Buddha usually spoke of the Sanātan Dharma, he sometimes used other synonymous terms for "Sanātan Dharma," such as "Akaliko Dharma," and "Poranako Dharma."

Can I know the all the verse numbers of scriptures, where Buddha mentioned "Sanātan Dharma" "Akaliko Dharma" and "Poranako Dharma." ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> sanantana
>
> adjective
>
> primeval; old; eternal

Doing a [quick search](https://suttacentral.net/search?query=sanantana), the Pali word '[sanantana](https://suttacentral.net/define/sanantana)' appears to be found rarely in the Pali suttas.

Apart from being used in references to the Vedic (pre-Hindu) teachings about 'Brahma' & 'Eternal Youth' in [DN 19](https://suttacentral.net/en/dn19), a [quick search](https://suttacentral.net/search?query=sanantana) finds '[sanantana](https://suttacentral.net/define/sanantana)' used in only two Buddhist phrases, as follows:

> Saccaṃ ve amatā vācā, esa dhammo **sanantano**; Sacce atthe ca dhamme
>   ca, āhu santo patiṭṭhitā.
>
> Truth indeed, is deathless speech — this is the **ancient/eternal** Dharma. On
>   truth, its study and practice both, they say are the Peaceful firm.
>
> [Snp 3.3](https://suttacentral.net/pi/snp3.3)

Most famously in the [Dhammapada](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.01.budd.html):

> Hatred is never appeased by hatred in this world. By non-hatred alone
>   is hatred appeased. This is a law **eternal**.
>
> Na hi verena verāni, sammantīdha kudācanaṃ; Averena ca sammanti, esa
>   dhammo **sanantano**.

---

The word '**porāṇaka**' appears to be not found in any teachings attributed to the Buddha; however appears found in later-day commentaries & Jataka Tales; as shown in this [search list](https://suttacentral.net/search?query=por%C4%81%E1%B9%87aka&lang=).

---

The word '[**akālika**](https://suttacentral.net/define/ak%C4%81lika)' is supremely important in Buddhism, being one of six attributes of the Dhamma spoken by the Buddha, as follows:

1. svākkhāto bhagavatā dhammo: perfectly spoken is the Dhamma of the Blessed One
2. sandiṭṭhiko: visible in the here-&-now
3. akāliko: immediately effective; without delay; 'timeless'
4. ehipassiko: inviting inspection
5. opaneyyiko: leading onwards (to experiencing here-&-now Nibbana)
6. paccattaṃ veditabbo viññūhī: to be verified by the wise for themselves.

Every morning and every evening, the above verse is chanted by Theravada Buddhists as the recollection of refuge in the Dhamma.

---

Since the word '*akāliko*' is often translated as '*timeless*', it appears the word '*akāliko*' might be mistaken for '*sanantana*' & '*porāṇaka*'. However, '*akāliko*' means '*immediate*' rather than '*eternal*'. In short, it appears the Pali word '*akāliko*' is not synonymous with  '*sanantana*' and '*porāṇaka*'.